# Does SSRS 2012 requires SharePoint 2013 enterprise licensing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

Just wanted to confirm whether SSRS 2012 requires  SharePoint 2013 Enterprise licensing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a table of whats included in with the different licenses of SharePoint.

[SharePoint feature availability across on-premises solutions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise)

**SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Integrated Mode**

- SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Yes
- SharePoint Server 2013 Standard CAL - Yes
- SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise CAL - Yes

However, you won't have the template for Business Intelligence Center without enterprise license so i can't answer how SSRS will work.